# Designing xml into OOP way

Tags: xml, oop, design-patterns

The structure of QCM will store something like

```
qcm.xml -->master node
   groups.xml -> list of groups
        group.xml -> group node
           questions.xml -> list of questions
                question.xml -> question node
                    anwsers.xml -> list of answers.
                        anwser.xml -> answer node
```

And for every of  `QCM, GROUP, QUESTION, ANSWER` will include:

```
content.xml
variant.xml
property.xml
```

Firts I could say `element` is smallest part:

```
  ELEMENT
    +content
    +property
    +dataListRef
```

XML content:

```
1.1) groups.xml ( list of groups::groupListRef)

<groups>
        <group id="123"></group>
        <group id="345"></group>
        <group id="567"></group>
</groups>
1.1.1) group.xml (group element)
    <group>
        <content id="123"></content>
        <property id="123"></property>
        <questionListRef id="123"></questionListRef>
    </group>
    1.1.1.1) questions.xml (list of questions::questionListRef)
            <questions id="123">
                    <question id="123"></question>
                    <question id="345"></question>
                    <question id="567"></question>
            </questions>            
            1.1.1.1.1)question.xml (question element)
                    <question id="123">
                        <content id="123"></content>
                        <property id="123"></property>      .
                        <answerListRef id="123"></answerListRef>    
                    <question>
                    1.1.1.1.1.1) answers.xml (list of answers belong to question::answerListRef)
                            <answers id="123">
                                <answer id="123"></answer>
                                <answer id="345"></answer>
                                <answer id="567"></answer>
                            <answers>
                                1.1.1.1.1.1.1) ...



1) content.xml
    <content id="123">
        <variant id="123"></variant>
    <content>
        a.1)variant.xml
            <variant id="123">
                <text></text>
                <image></image>
                <table></table>
                <file></file>
            </variant>
2) property.xml
    <property id="123">
        <segment></segment>
        <context></context>
    </property>
```

My ways( I am not good in oop ):

```
<?php 
interface element {
    public content //obj of content
    public property //obj of property
    public listRef //array of obj [123,321,253]

}
class content{
    //some property
    //some property
}
class propery{
    //some property
    //some property
}
class listRef {
    //some property
    //some property
}

class group implements  element{
    //some property
    //some property
}
class question implements  element{
    //some property
    //some property
}
class answer implements  element{
    //some property
    //some property
}
?>
```

Could anybody give some guidelines to design this case  into OOP ways?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less your class model would be something like this

```
abstract class Element {
    int id;
    public Content content;//obj of content
    public Property property;//obj of property


}
class Content{
    int id;
    Variant variant;
}
class Propery{
   int id;
   String segment,context;
}

 class Variant {
     int id;
     String text, image, table, file;  
  }

  public class Qcm extends Element {

      List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Groups>();     


}

public class Group extends Element {

    List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();       


}

public class Question extends Element {

    List<Anwser> anwsers = new ArrayList<Anwser>();     


}
public class Answer extends Element {


}
```

If you do it like this, you have to go into an element to get any of the children. For instance to access an answer, you need to go into the question. If you prefer to have everything independent, and in the parent fields just keep a reference to the children, you can change it following this logic:

```
public class Question extends Element {

    int answerListRef;


}
SparseArray<ArrayList<Anwser>> answerLists = new  SparseArray<ArrayList<Anwser>>();
```

Like this, instead of having the list of answers inside the question, you have an outer list of list, indexed by their id. So if you have a question, you can access the list of answers by:

```
ArrayList<Anwser> anwersOfThisQuestion=  answerLists.get(question.answerListRef);
```

of course, you can decide if having all the fields publics, or making them private, and then use getters and setters to access it, something like this:

```
public class Question extends Element {

    private int answerListRef;
    public void setAnswerListRef(int answerListRef){
       this.answerListRef=answerListRef;
    }

    public void getAnswerListRef( ){
     return answerListRef;
    }



}
```